# CollectionView using NSDiffableDataSource with UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: uicollectionview, swiftui, uicollectionviewflowlayout, nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot

When I use UICollectionView with UICollectionViewFlowLayout set. And then try to apply snapshots of datasource via

```
// load initial data
        reloadDataSource()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3)) {
            self.reloadDataSource(animating: true)
        }
```

I am getting crash on second snapshot applied after 3 seconds delay. 
The crash is happening only when animating: true

If I set animating to false then there is no crash but the collection view if left empty.

Here is this mathod applying data source

```
extension CollectionViewController {

    func reloadDataSource(animating: Bool = false) {

        print("reloading data source with snapshot -> \(snapshot.numberOfItems)")

        self.dataSource.apply(self.snapshot, animatingDifferences: animating) {
            print("applying snapshot completed!")
        }
    }
}
```

Data source is just

```
let dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(collectionView: collectionView, cellProvider: cellProvider)
```

Full project you can play (may changes over time): https://github.com/michzio/SwifUICollectionView

Update

I've tried to simplify example and do something like this and it doesn't work correctly. It seems that moving .apply() to background queue, other queue causes empty data in collectionview

```
func reloadDataSource(animating: Bool = false) {

        print("reloading data source with snapshot -> \(snapshot.numberOfItems)")
        diffQueue.async {
            var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
            snapshot.appendSections([.categories])
            snapshot.appendItems(Item.categoryItems)

            self.dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animating) {
                print("applying snapshot completed!")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems that i found the reason of all my errors with updating datasource by applying new snapshots

This lazy var dataSource is causing errors:

```
private(set) lazy var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item> = {
        let dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(collectionView: collectionView, cellProvider: cellProvider)
        //dataSource.supplementaryViewProvider = supplementaryViewProvider
        return dataSource
    }()
```

I've changed it to

```
private(set) var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>!
```

and after configureCollectionView in viewDidLoad() 
now I am calling configureDataSource() that does what was in lazy var initializer.